# Can overheating destroy a video card?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, fan, overheating

Recently, a circuit breaker tripped in my home and my desktop lost power. Upon turning it back on, one of my monitors wasn't functioning. I have three monitors supported by two video cards, and I just worked the rest of the day with two monitors.

When I opened up the computer to investigate, I found that the fans on the video card supporting the disabled monitor had completely seized; spinning them lightly with my finger was actually somewhat difficult. The card is about 4 or 5 years old so I suppose the fans might have just been at the end of their natural lives. The card affected is an MSI R5770 Hawk.

So, I set about disassembling the heatsink assembly and eventually disassembled the fans themselves, relubricated the parts (which were exceeding gummy by this point) and reassembled the card. However, upon attempting to use the card again, it's still not functioning.

Windows can detect the card within Device Manager (Windows 8.1), however in the device properties it displays "*Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)*"

My questions are these:

- Is it possible that the card has been destroyed somehow without functioning fans?
- Why would losing power have been the point at which the card stopped working?
- How better can I diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible that the card has been destroyed somehow without functioning fans?

Yes. Excessive heat reduces component life. Some of the parts have thermal safeties, but many of them don't.

> Why would losing power have been the point at which the card stopped working?

There are three possible reasons. One is just coincidence. Another is that stopping or starting puts additional stresses on components, particularly when it's stopping due to loss of external power. Lastly, it's possible that it failed before the power was lost, but failed in a way that prevented it from starting correctly but didn't have any other obvious consequences.

> How better can I diagnose this problem?

There's probably not a whole lot you can do. If the fans are spinning and the heat sink is properly mounted and the card still doesn't work, you can pretty much consider it dead.

Comment: Another reason for ending the life of the card at that point in time is that electricity is more complicated than on/off - especially if triggering a circuit breaker is involved. There may have been a voltage spike applied to the card and the fan, which fried them. PSUs are designed to reduce the likelihood that this happens, but they can't always prevent it.